# Derivative word problem - $s''(t) = a$, i.e the acceleration is constant and $(1) [s'(t)]^2 = 2as(t)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Hi Guys I'm having trouble with $\eqref a$ and a lot more with $\eqref b$. I'm assuming for $\eqref a$ that we must first show why $c$ was switched $c$ to $\frac{a}{2}$. However after that I can't seem to figure it out, and the same goes with $\eqref b$. Any help would be great! Thank You!

Prove that the following facts are true about $s$ if $s(t) = \frac a 2 t^2$

$$s''(t) = a,\tag a\label a$$ i.e., the acceleration is constant

$$(s'(t))^2 = 2as(t)\tag b\label b$$

Comment: The question is tagged "derivatives," but I don't see any derivatives here?

Comment: Changing your question to something completely different isn't nice (see the [revisions](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/578770/revisions)). Why did you do that?

Comment: And regardless of why you did it, **don't** do it again. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I think the reason is that the OP errornously reasked what he posted [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579263/derivative-proofs-c-prove-that-the-following-facts-are-true-about-s-if-s) and then decided to use this post for a new question. That's why I asked. But you're right **don't** do it again...

Comment: @Lord_Farin lol u guys are serious eh

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a $c$ anywhere in your problem statement, so I don't understand that part of your question.

The way it is written, you are only being asked to do the derivatives and confirm the relations given.  That should be straightforward, no integrals or differential equations are asked for.  Just do the derivatives and then plug the results into the relations to verify they are equal.

BTW, is your use of ' meant to indicate $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ or $\dfrac{dy}{dt}$?  Since you didn't state whether your problem came from a math course or a physics course, it is hard to know which convention is assumed.

Comment: Note that the prior question asks you to show why the solution is __not__ in that form, so you shouldn't be surprised that there is no 'c' in the new form you are given.