# Derivative Proofs - (c) Prove that the following facts are true about $s$ if $s(t) = (a/2)t ^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Hi guys I'm really having trouble with (b) and (c). I did question (a) so thats outta the way but I'm really stuck on these two. I've been working on them for the whole weekend and can't seem to figure them out. They're practice questions for an upcoming test so any help would be great.

(b) If a body falls a distance $s(t)$ in $t$ seconds, and $s'$ is proportional to $s$, i.e. $s' = ds$ for some constant $d \in \mathbb{R}$, then $s$ cannot be a function of the form $s(t) = ct^2$ for some constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

(c) Prove that the following facts are true about $s$ if $s(t) = (a/2)t^2$:

(i) $s''(t) = a$   i.e. the acceleration is constant.

(ii) $[s'(t)]^2 = 2as(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that every solution to the differential equation $y = ky'$ has the form $y(x) = ce^{kx}$, where $c$ and $k$ are constants. But then $y(x) \neq dx^2$, where $d$ is a constant, unless both $c$ and $d$ are zero. This should suffice to solve the first part of your problem. To solve the second part, we compute the derivatives $s'(t) = at$ and $s''(t) = a$ of the function $s(t) = at^2/2$, where $a$ is a constant. We see that $s''(t)$ is constant, solving the first branch of the problem. To solve the second branch, compute
  $$ (s'(t))^2 ~ = ~ (at)^2 ~ = ~ a^2t^2 ~ = ~ (2a)(at^2/2) ~ = ~ 2as(t) $$